# Python: Loop through .txt file and count the occurrences of an item

Tags: python

If I have a .txt file that has a number on each line, example:

```
7
7
6
5
4
3
1
```

And I wanted to cycle through the contents of the file and count the number of each integer (example the number 7 is listed twice, so I would have 2), what would be the best approach?  Below is what I currently have:

```
fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
infile = open(fname, "r")
data = infile.readline()

mylist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in infile:
    mylist[int(i)] = mylist[int(i)]+1
```

This does not seem to be working.  When I print mylist[2] for example, it should give me the count of 2's in the file.  In this case, they are all remaining 0 as I assigned them previously.

Comment: @jsfan That's not how iterating through a file works...

Comment: Can you show us your test code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code actually works, with one exception, commented below:

```
fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
infile = open(fname, "r")
data = infile.readline() # you never use this

mylist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in infile:
    mylist[int(i)] = mylist[int(i)]+1
```

Where the comment is mentioned, you basically take the first line of the file and throw it away. Otherwise, I am able to run this code successfully. Is there another snippet of code not shown that may be causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a count value for each number in the file, use a dictionary to assign a value. if there is a single number on each line only this should work.

```
fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
infile = open(fname, "r")
data = infile.readlines()

mylist = {}
for i in data:
    if int(i) in mylist:
        mylist[int(i)] += 1
    else:
        mylist[int(i)] = 1

print my list

output example = {8: 2, 9: 2, 7: 5}
```

Comment: Welcome. It's a subclass of a dictionary, so it's a direct replacement, basically

Answer (score -1):

Heres a method that probably does what you need using the collections module

```
from collections import Counter

def print_top(filename):
    """
    receives a file path, opens it, counts how many times each word appeared in the file and prints the top 20 most
    common words in the file and the amount of times they appeared in a "'word' has appeared 'amount' times" format
    """
    input_file = open(filename, "r")
    wordcount = Counter(input_file.read().split())
    top_20_tuple_list = wordcount.most_common(20)  # finds the top 20 most common words in the wordcount dictionary
    for i in range(len(top_20_tuple_list)):  # and puts them in a list made of tuples in a (word, count) format
        print "%s has appeared in the text %d times" % (top_20_tuple_list[i][0], top_20_tuple_list[i][1])
    input_file.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, his question is why HIS code doesn't work, not how to solve a general problem.

Comment: @Natecat The question did ask "what would be the best approach?"

Comment: He asked "what would be the best approach?" Using Counter from the collections module is definitely a good approach in my opinion..

Comment: I agree with `Counter`, but I don't think that the `read().split()` or `most_common()` is the best approach

Comment: Ah this is just some old code I had that happened to do what he wanted. The format of the file that was sent to this method was very specific. I just wanted to show that using Counter for what he wanted was a good way, guess I should have emphasized that